# Augmented Reality packages for flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, augmented-reality

Is there any augmented reality tool or library or packages for  flutter?
I'm new in both fields so I have absolutely no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can using this: [arkit_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/arkit_plugin)